# Detect running applications in a system

Tags: javascript

I want to know is how to write a javascript or any other language using which we can identify which applications are running on a system (foreground or background) ?.

Comment: Python can be a better choice

Comment: I have never used python. Do u know what command can I use?

Comment: thanx...found some solutions on stack over flow ..